# OneTimeTearDown not executing C# UI Testing

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, ui-automation

I am having trouble getting a teardown to execute that is supposed to delete all of the accounts my automation creates on our application. I elected to use a OneTimeTearDown so it executes once and just goes through the list but it doesn't seem to be executing. Here is the code, am I putting it in the wrong place maybe? The code in the teardown works as intended on its own if I just add it to the end of the test.

```
    namespace Ag.AutomatedRegression.UI.Tests.AccountsTests
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class AccountsPageTests : BaseSetup
        {
            [OneTimeTearDown]
            public void CleanUpAccounts()
            {
    
                LogList.Add($"Entered the {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}().");
                for (int i = AccountsPageTests.accountIdList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (AccountsPageTests.accountIdList.Count == 0)
                    {
                        LogList.Add("There were no ids in the list to delete.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LogList.Add("Next Step: Clean Up accounts created this session.");
                        PerformBrowserManagerAction.NavigateToURL(CommonSettings.Default.URL);
                        PerformCommonStagesAction.CleanUpAccounts(CommonSettings.Default.UserName,
                                                                  CommonSettings.Default.EncryptedPassword,
                                                                  AccountsPageTests.accountIdList[i]);
                    }
    
                    LogList.Add("Account Cleanup was successful.");
                }
            }
            public static List accountIdList = new List();
            
    
    
            [Test]
            public void CreateAccountTest()
            {
                LogList.Add($"Entered the {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}().");
    
                //Code to create account with account id string variable
               
                Assert.That(Success, Is.True, expectedMessage + "\r\n" + 
        actualMessage);    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please properly indent your code? Because I'm getting the impression that your test belongs to another class than your cleanup method

Comment: @mu88 tried to adjust that. Both the teardown and test are within the test fixture on the same level.

Comment: It's still wrong: your method `CreateAccountTest` is outside the class `AccountsPageTests`, but it has to be a part of it. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Make sure that all components (`[OneTimeTearDown]` and `[Test]`) are part of the same `[TestFixture]` ([see here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/onetimeteardown.html#example))

Comment: @mu88 they are like that, it just isn't formatting correctly on this. Like I said, the One time teardown and the test are in the test fixture and the test fixture is in the AccountsPageTests class.

Comment: _and the test fixture is in the AccountsPageTests class_ → the test fixture cannot _be_ in the class - the test fixture is an attribute _of_ the class. And the fact that your code isn't formatted correctly on SO implies that there is still something wrong. I'll post an answer where the code is properly formatted.

Comment: @mu88 Tried to format it as best as I could, is that readable now?

Comment: See my answer 

Answer (score 0):

The indexing on your statement

```
for (int i = AccountsPageTests.accountIdList.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

doesn't do what you want. It will never process list item 0 and if there is only 1 item, nothing will show.

Step through it mentally, assuming one item

- Count - 1 is 0
- 0 is not greater than 0
- so no items are executed

Change `i > 0' to` i >= 0`

Comment: Thanks for catching that! However the teardown is still not operating correctly. It is not executing still

Answer (score 0):

As we were already discussing in the comments, please try whether formatting is an issue of your class:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Your.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class AccountsPageTests : BaseSetup
    {
        private List<string> accountIdList = new List<string>();

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void CleanUpAccounts()
        {
            LogList.Add($"Entered the {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}().");
            for (int i = AccountsPageTests.accountIdList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (AccountsPageTests.accountIdList.Count == 0)
                {
                    LogList.Add("There were no ids in the list to delete.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    LogList.Add("Next Step: Clean Up accounts created this session.");
                    PerformBrowserManagerAction.NavigateToURL(CommonSettings.Default.StagesURL);
                    PerformCommonAction.CleanUpAccounts(CommonSettings.Default.StagesUserName,
                                                            CommonSettings.Default.StagesEncryptedPassword,
                                                            AccountsPageTests.accountIdList[i]);
                }

                LogList.Add("Account Cleanup was successful.");
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void CreateAccountTest()
        {
            LogList.Add($"Entered the {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}().");
            //Code to Create account with accountId as a string 
            accountIdList.Add(accountId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting was correct after mu88's answer, but that didn't fix the teardown, I ended up making it a standard Teardown instead and that seems to have resolved the issue.